# How to change the InstallShield installation wizard icon?

Tags: .net, installshield

I have a setup that first install a prerequisite (.NET framework 4.0), so, on this prerequisite installation window I'd like to change the InstallShield icon to one personalized one, and change the window title too.

[1 http://hosted.comm100.com/KnowledgeBase/Main/Preview.aspx?id=100184&siteId=49677](http://hosted.comm100.com/KnowledgeBase/Main/Preview.aspx?id=100184&siteId=49677)

Is that possible?

Comment: What version of InstallShield are you asking for?  It's really the same in all versions but I've noticed in your other questions that you will complain that the answer was given for a version different then the one you are using.  Also that you've only accepted 1 out of 7 answers.

Comment: It's to 2009. Sorry for all the complications in other questions. But now, I just want to change the icon and the title of this page (like the image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the InstallShield manual:

[Setup.exe Tab for a Release](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/ReleaseGridSetupTab.htm)

> Setup.exe Icon File
>
> To use your own icon for the Setup.exe file, specify the fully
>   qualified name of the file that contains the icon. To specify a file,
>   type an absolute path or a path that is relative to a path variable,
>   or click the ellipsis button (...) to browse to the file from within
>   the Change Icon dialog box.
>
> By default, the icon with index 0 is used; to specify a different
>   icon, either select an icon in the Change Icon dialog box or append
>   the icon’s index or resource ID (preceded by a minus sign) to the file
>   name. For example, C:\Temp\MyLibrary.dll,2 indicates the icon with an
>   index of 2, and C:\Temp\MyLibrary.dll,-100 indicates the icon with a
>   resource ID of 100.
>
> If you leave this setting blank, InstallShield uses a default icon for
>   your Setup.exe file.

Comment: Let me see if I understood, if I add an icon with an index of 2, installShield will select this icon to this window (Prerequisite install)? Is that what you are saying? And how to change the title?

Comment: A DLL can contain more then one icon.  The number 2 is just a way of referencing the second icon in the dll.  If you leave it blank it'll take the first one it finds.  It has nothing to do with saying you want to change it for this dialog.  Also, you can't change the title of this dialog.

Comment: Hey man, can you help me again? Now I'd like to make a pack of it. Because like that (prerequisites) when I build the setup, it creates a folder containing the prerequisite's setup. Now I have to make that all of it be just one executable. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705549/how-to-pack-a-installation-framework-application-in-one-executable/9705585#9705585

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield 2013:

You must ***first build a release*** - and at that do so by using the project assistant Build Installation Screen and the Build Installation button at the bottom of that (those details tripped me up).  After that, click the "Installation Design Tab", then expand "Media" and click "Releases".  Then select a release (which only appears after you've built one!), and click the "Setup.exe" tab.  There you will find entry an in list of properties where you can specify the "Setup exe Icon File".

On an immediately related note, you can change the name of the setup.exe file too.  In the tree where you selected the release, is a parent level, i.e. "Product Configuration 1" or "PROJECT_ASSISTANT" - select that.  In the "General" tab, there is a property called "Setup File Name".  By default, it is just plain "setup".  Change that to whatever you want, e.g. "MyProgramSetup".